# Is Guarantee Type attribute required for OTA_HotelResRQ

Tags: sabre

I have a hotel returning no Guarantee Types such as G, GDPST, etc... This is the first I've seen of this and due to the way the code was written it defaults to the first in an array if the property does not return one. In this case "G". When I perform an OTA_HotelResRQ I get the following error:

> INVLD PROP REQUIRES A DEPOSIT FOR THIS DATE

In this scenario should I omit the **Type** attribute (as specified here http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/OTA_HotelResLLSRQ_v2.2.0_Design.xml) from the **Guarantee** node?

Here is the HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">REMOVED</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>REMOVED</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>MyConversationID</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>471353037366360202</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2016-09-14T01:02:16</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>1422291197</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESC!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3361979970612623474!1331042!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.1">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
  <stl:Success timeStamp="2016-09-13T20:02:16-05:00"/>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
 <RoomStay>
  <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="UZ" GeoConfidenceLevel="1" HotelCityCode="TSM" HotelCode="0012498" HotelName="HOTEL LA FONDA DE TAOS" Latitude="36.406883" Longitude="-105.57462" NumFloors="3" RPH="001">
   <Address>
    <AddressLine>108 SOUTH PLAZA</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>TAOS NM 87571</AddressLine>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
   </Address>
   <Award Provider="NTM3 CROWN"/>
   <ContactNumbers>
    <ContactNumber Fax="1-57-57588508" Phone="1-57-57582211"/>
   </ContactNumbers>
   <DirectConnect Ind="true">
    <AdditionalData Ind="false"/>
    <CurrencyConverted Ind="true"/>
    <DC_AvailParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <DC_SellParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <RequestFail Ind="false"/>
    <UnAvail Ind="false"/>
   </DirectConnect>
   <IndexData>
    <Index CountryState="NM" DistanceDirection="0NW" LocationCode="A" Point="TAOS SKI VALLEY" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="16W" LocationCode="C" Point="AXX" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="66NE" LocationCode="R" Point="LAM" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="73W" LocationCode="R" Point="RTN" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="7SE" LocationCode="A" Point="TSM" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="72NE" LocationCode="R" Point="SAF" TransportationCode="O"/>
   </IndexData>
   <PropertyOptionInfo>
    <ADA_Accessible Ind="false"/>
    <AdultsOnly Ind="false"/>
    <AirportShuttle Ind="false"/>
    <BeachFront Ind="false"/>
    <Breakfast Ind="false"/>
    <BusinessCenter Ind="true"/>
    <BusinessReady Ind="false"/>
    <CarRentalCounter>Y</CarRentalCounter>
    <Conventions Ind="false"/>
    <Dataport Ind="false"/>
    <Dining Ind="true"/>
    <DryClean Ind="false"/>
    <EcoCertified Ind="false"/>
    <ExecutiveFloors Ind="false"/>
    <FamilyPlan Ind="true"/>
    <FitnessCenter Ind="false"/>
    <FreeLocalCalls Ind="false"/>
    <FreeParking Ind="true"/>
    <FreeShuttle Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInMeetingRooms Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInPublicSpaces Ind="false"/>
    <FreeWifiInRooms Ind="false"/>
    <FullServiceSpa Ind="false"/>
    <GameFacilities Ind="true"/>
    <Golf Ind="false"/>
    <GovtSafetyFire Ind="false"/>
    <HighSpeedInternet Ind="true"/>
    <HypoallergenicRooms Ind="false"/>
    <IndoorPool Ind="true"/>
    <IndPetRestriction Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomCoffeeTea Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomMiniBar Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomRefrigerator Ind="false"/>
    <InRoomSafe Ind="false"/>
    <InteriorDoorways Ind="false"/>
    <Jacuzzi Ind="false"/>
    <KidsFacilities Ind="false"/>
    <KitchenFacilities Ind="false"/>
    <MealService Ind="false"/>
    <MeetingFacilities Ind="true"/>
    <NoAdultTV Ind="false"/>
    <NonSmoking Ind="true"/>
    <OutdoorPool Ind="false"/>
    <Parking>Y-COMPLIMENTARY</Parking>
    <Pets Ind="false"/>
    <Pool Ind="true"/>
    <PublicTransportationAdjacent Ind="false"/>
    <Recreation Ind="false"/>
    <RestrictedRoomAccess Ind="false"/>
    <RoomService Ind="false"/>
    <RoomService24Hours Ind="false"/>
    <RoomsWithBalcony Ind="false"/>
    <SkiInOutProperty Ind="false"/>
    <SmokeFree Ind="false"/>
    <SmokingRoomsAvail Ind="false"/>
    <Tennis Ind="false"/>
    <WaterPurificationSystem Ind="false"/>
    <Wheelchair Ind="false"/>
   </PropertyOptionInfo>
   <PropertyTypeInfo>
    <AllInclusive Ind="false"/>
    <Apartments Ind="false"/>
    <BedBreakfast Ind="false"/>
    <Castle Ind="false"/>
    <Conventions Ind="false"/>
    <Economy Ind="false"/>
    <ExtendedStay Ind="false"/>
    <Farm Ind="false"/>
    <First Ind="false"/>
    <Luxury Ind="false"/>
    <Moderate Ind="true"/>
    <Motel Ind="false"/>
    <Resort Ind="true"/>
    <Suites Ind="false"/>
   </PropertyTypeInfo>
   <SpecialOffers Ind="false"/>
   <Taxes>
    <Text>8.18 PCT</Text>
    <Text>5.00 PCT</Text>
   </Taxes>
   <VendorMessages>
    <Attractions>
     <Text>PRIMARY CITY -</Text>
     <Text>SAF - TAOS</Text>
     <Text>65 MI S</Text>
     <Text>RIO GRANDE GORGE          12 MI</Text>
     <Text>TAOS PUEBLO               3 MI</Text>
     <Text>TAOS SKI VALLEY           18 MI</Text>
    </Attractions>
    <Awards>
     <Text>3 STARS</Text>
    </Awards>
    <Cancellation>
     <Text>-27FEB11 - END -</Text>
     <Text>CANCEL BY 7 DAYS PRIOR TO 0000 HOURS ON DAY OF ARRIVAL,</Text>
     <Text>LOCAL HOTEL TIME TO AVOID A CANCELLATION PENALTY</Text>
     <Text>CANCELLATION POLICY TEXT -</Text>
     <Text>CANCEL BY 10 00 7 DAYS BEFORE ARRIVAL TO AVOID PENALTY</Text>
     <Text>OF 1 NIGHT.</Text>
    </Cancellation>
    <Deposit>
     <Text>-27FEB11 - END MON-SUN</Text>
     <Text>1 NIGHT DEPOSIT REQUIRED FOR ALL RESERVATIONS</Text>
     <Text>DEPOSIT OF FIRST NIGHT STAY</Text>
     <Text>ACCEPTED FORMS OF DEPOSIT-</Text>
     <Text>CREDIT CARD</Text>
    </Deposit>
    <Description>
     <Text>- HOTEL</Text>
     <Text>RESORT</Text>
     <Text>YEAR BUILT - 1890            YEAR REMODELED - 2003</Text>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL PROPERTY DESCRIPTION -</Text>
     <Text>HISTORICAL BOUTIQUE HOTEL LOCATED ON THE FAMOUS TAOS</Text>
     <Text>PLAZA. AUTHENTIC SOUTHWESTERN AMBIENCE WITH MODERN</Text>
     <Text>AMENITIES.</Text>
    </Description>
    <Dining>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL MEAL PLAN DESCRIPTION -</Text>
     <Text>WALKING TO BENT STREET CAFE/GRAHAMS GRILL/DOC</Text>
     <Text>MARTINS/ALLEY CANTINA/ESKES BREWPUB/MICHAELS KITCHEN</Text>
     <Text>RESTAURANT</Text>
     <Text>RESTAURANT DESCRIPTION -</Text>
     <Text>WALKING TO BENT STREET CAFE/GRAHAMS GRILL/DOC</Text>
     <Text>MARTINS/ALLEY CANTINA/ESKES BREWPUB/MICHAELS KITCHEN</Text>
    </Dining>
    <Directions>
     <Text>DIRECTION TO THE PROPERTY FROM AIRPORT SAF -</Text>
     <Text>65 MI  NORTH</Text>
    </Directions>
    <Facilities>
     <Text>ON-SITE FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>GENERAL FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>BANQUET FACILITY            CASINO</Text>
     <Text>COFFEE SHOP                 ELEVATORS</Text>
     <Text>INDOOR POOL                 MEETING ROOM</Text>
     <Text>NON-SMOKING ROOMS           RESTAURANT</Text>
     <Text>SOLARIUM                    SPA</Text>
     <Text>HIGH SPEED WIRELESS</Text>
     <Text>FREE HIGH SPEED INTERNET CONNECTION</Text>
     <Text>CHARGEABLE FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>BUSINESS CENTER</Text>
     <Text>PARKING FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>FREE PARKING</Text>
     <Text>PUBLIC AREA FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>HIGH SPEED INTERNET ACCESS</Text>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL ONSITE FACILITIES -</Text>
     <Text>120 AC  120 DC  24-HOUR FRONT DESK  24-HOUR SECURITY  3</Text>
     <Text>BEDROOM SUITE  ACCESSIBLE PARKING  ACCOMMODATIONS WITH</Text>
     <Text>BALCONY  ADJOINING ROOMS  ADJOINING ROOMS  ADJOINING</Text>
     <Text>ROOMS OR SUITES  AIR CONDITIONED GUEST ROOMS  AIR</Text>
     <Text>CONDITIONING  AIRPORT - ALBUQUERQUE SUNPORT 140 MILES</Text>
     <Text>AIRPORT SHUTTLE - 50.0  ALARM CLOCK  ALL NEWS CHANNEL</Text>
     <Text>ALL PETS - PETS NOT ALLOWED  ALL PUBLIC AREAS</Text>
     <Text>NON-SMOKING  ALL ROOMS NON-SMOKING  AMERICANS WITH</Text>
     <Text>DISABILITIES ACT  ADA  COMPLIANCE  ANIMAL WATCHING</Text>
     <Text>ANTIQUE SHOPPING  ARCHEOLOGICAL  ARCHERY  AUDIO VISUAL</Text>
     <Text>EQUIPMENT  AV EQUIP  AVAILABLE SUITES  AWAY FROM THE</Text>
     <Text>ELEVATOR  BACK OF BUILDING  BACKGROUND MUSIC  BAGGAGE</Text>
     <Text>HOLD  BALCONY/LANAI/TERRACE  BASKETBALL COURT  BATHROOM</Text>
     <Text>AMENITIES  BATHROOM VANITY IN GUEST ROOMS FOR DISABLED</Text>
     <Text>PERSON HEIGHT  BATHTUB  BATHTUB/SHOWER COMBINATION  BED</Text>
     <Text>TYPES OF WHEELCHAIR ACCESSIBLE ROOMS  BEDROOM</Text>
     <Text>WHEELCHAIR ACCESS  BICYCLE  BICYCLE RENTALS  BIKE TRAIL</Text>
     <Text>BILINGUAL STAFF  BIRD WATCHING  BLACKBOARD  BLACKBOARD</Text>
     <Text>WITH ERASER   CHALK  BOARDING PASS PRINT-OUT AVAILABLE</Text>
     <Text>BOATING  BOOKSTORE  BOTTLED WATER  BOUTIQUE  BRIDGE</Text>
     <Text>BUS  BUS PARKING  BUSINESS LOCATION  CABLE TELEVISION</Text>
     <Text>CALLING CARD CALLS  CALLING CARD CALLS  CAMPING</Text>
     <Text>CANOEING  CAR  CARDIOVASCULAR EXERCISE  CATERED</Text>
     <Text>BREAKFAST  CATERED DINNER  CATERED LUNCH  CATERING</Text>
     <Text>CATHEDRAL  CEILING FAN  CEMETERY  CERTIFIED WEDDING</Text>
     <Text>PLANNER  CHAIR PROVIDED WITH DESK  CHARM HOTEL</Text>
     <Text>CHILDREN NOT ALLOWED</Text>
    </Facilities>
    <Guarantee>
     <Text>-27FEB11 - END MON-SUN</Text>
     <Text>SEE DEPOSIT POLICY</Text>
     <Text>ACCEPTED FORMS OF GUARANTEE-</Text>
     <Text>CREDIT CARD</Text>
     <Text>ACCEPTED FORMS OF PAYMENT-</Text>
     <Text>CREDIT CARD</Text>
    </Guarantee>
    <Location>
     <Text>PRIMARY PROPERTY LOCATION - CITY</Text>
     <Text>SAF AIRPORT                   65 MI N</Text>
     <Text>RESORT</Text>
    </Location>
    <MiscServices>
     <Text>EMAIL - INFO LAFONDATAOS.COM</Text>
     <Text>TAXES AND SURCHARGES -</Text>
     <Text>TAX- 8.18 PCT</Text>
     <Text>LODGING TAX-    5.00 PCT</Text>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL CURRENCY AND TAX INFORMATION -</Text>
     <Text>8.1875 PCT VAT AND 5 PCT LODGERS TAX EXCLUDED</Text>
     <Text>-27FEB11 - END MON-SUN</Text>
     <Text>MIN STAY - 1</Text>
    </MiscServices>
    <Policies>
     <Text>EXTRA CHILD - 0.00 USD     ROLLAWAY FOR CHILD - 0.00 USD</Text>
     <Text>CHILDREN STAY FREE -</Text>
     <Text>CHILDREN WELCOME - NO CHILDREN ALLOWED UNDER AGE 8</Text>
     <Text>NO PETS ALLOWED -</Text>
     <Text>ALL PETS - PETS NOT ALLOWED</Text>
     <Text>PROPERTY OFFERS COMMISSION - RATE OF COMMISSION</Text>
     <Text>10 PCT</Text>
     <Text>ADDITIONAL COMMISSION PROGRAMS INFORMATION -</Text>
     <Text>10 PCT</Text>
    </Policies>
    <Recreation>
     <Text>ON-SITE RECREATION -</Text>
     <Text>BICYCLING                   WATER SPORTS</Text>
    </Recreation>
    <Rooms>
     <Text>ROOM AMENITIES FOR ALL ROOMS -</Text>
     <Text>ROOM AMENITIES -</Text>
     <Text>AIR CONDITIONING / AM/FM ALARM CLOCK / BATH TUB /</Text>
     <Text>BATHROOM AMENITIES / CABLE/SATELLITE TV / DIRECT DIAL</Text>
     <Text>TELEPHONE / FREE LOCAL TELEPHONE CALLS / HAIRDRYER /</Text>
     <Text>IRON/IRONING BOARD / NO SMOKING ROOM / PRIVATE BATH OR</Text>
     <Text>SHOWER / RADIO / SHOWER / SMOKE DETECTOR / TELEPHONE/SAFE/</Text>
     <Text>TELEVISION</Text>
     <Text>TECHNOLOGY -</Text>
     <Text>DATAPORT / HIGH SPEED INTERNET ACCESS / VOICE MAIL</Text>
     <Text>S1K-</Text>
     <Text>MAX OCCUPANCY - 4</Text>
     <Text>MAX NBR OF ROLLAWAYS - 0</Text>
     <Text>ROOM DESCRIPTION -</Text>
     <Text>NEWLY AND RICHLY REMODELED/ DELUXE TWO ROOM SUITE WITH</Text>
     <Text>1 KING BED. NEWLY AND RICHLY REMODELED/ DELUXE TWO ROOM</Text>
     <Text>SUITE WITH 1 KING BED/ SOME WITH SLEEPER SOFA/ MOST</Text>
     <Text>WITH GAS FIREPLACE/ REFRIGERATOR/ WET BAR/ LUXURIOUS</Text>
     <Text>LINENS AND HEADBOARD/ A/C CEILING FAN/ ARMOIRE WITH</Text>
     <Text>COLOR CABLE TV/ DSL CONNECTIVITY/ TELEPHONE WITH VOICE</Text>
     <Text>MAIL/ ALARM CLOCK/ RADIO/ SMOKE DETECTOR/ HAND-TILED</Text>
     <Text>BATHROOM WITH TUB AND SHOWER/ BATHROOM AMENITIES/</Text>
     <Text>IRON/BOARD/ AND HAIRDRYER. 120AC/ 120DC. DAILY MAID</Text>
     <Text>SERVICE/ FREE PARKING AND ADMITTANCE TO DH  LAWRENCE</Text>
     <Text>FORBIDDEN ART COLLECTION. ALL ROOMS ARE NON-SMOKING.</Text>
     <Text>PHR -</Text>
     <Text>MAX OCCUPANCY - 4</Text>
     <Text>MAX NBR OF ROLLAWAYS - 0</Text>
     <Text>ROOM DESCRIPTION -</Text>
     <Text>UNIQUE/ LUXURIOUS 1200 SQ. FT. PLAZA PENTHOUSE/ ONE</Text>
     <Text>BEDROOM WITH KING BED/ QUEEN SLEEPER SOFA. UNIQUE/</Text>
     <Text>LUXURIOUS 1200 SQ. FT. PLAZA PENTHOUSE/ ONE BEDROOM</Text>
     <Text>WITH KING BED/ QUEEN SLEEPER SOFA/ HAND-TILED FULL</Text>
     <Text>BATH/ LAUNDRY/ FULLY EQUIPPED KITCHEN/ DINING ROOM/</Text>
     <Text>SUNKEN LIVING ROOM WITH GAS KIVA FIREPLACE/ OUTDOOR</Text>
     <Text>DECKL/ COLOR CABLE TV/ DESK TOP COMPUTER/ DSL</Text>
     <Text>CONNECTIVITY/ CEILING FANS/ TELEPHONE WITH VOICE MAIL/</Text>
     <Text>ALARM CLOCK/ RADIO/ BATH AMENITIES/ HAIR DRYER/ IRON</Text>
     <Text>AND IRONING BOARD/ DAILY MAID SERVICE/ FREE PARKING AND</Text>
     <Text>ADMITTANCE TO DH LAWRENCE FORBIDDEN ART COLLECTION.</Text>
     <Text>TWO/ THREE/ AND FOUR BEDROOM CAPABILITY.  CALL FOR</Text>
     <Text>PRICES AND AVAILABILITY.  THIS HOTEL IS A NON-SMOKING</Text>
     <Text>PROPERTY AND CANNOT ACCOMMODATE PETS. THIS SUITE IS</Text>
     <Text>NON-SMOKING.</Text>
     <Text>A1Q -</Text>
     <Text>MAX OCCUPANCY -</Text>
    </Rooms>
    <Safety>
     <Text>PROPERTY SAFETY AND SECURITY -</Text>
     <Text>SECURITY AVAILABLE 24 HOURS</Text>
     <Text>24-HOUR SECURITY</Text>
    </Safety>
    <Services>
     <Text>ON-SITE GENERAL SERVICES -</Text>
     <Text>BAGGAGE HOLD                BICYCLE RENTAL</Text>
     <Text>FRONT DESK  24 HRS          MULTILINGUAL STAFF</Text>
     <Text>SAFE DEPOSIT BOX            WAKE-UP CALLS</Text>
     <Text>ON-SITE CHARGEABLE SERVICES -</Text>
     <Text>CAR RENTAL</Text>
     <Text>BUSINESS SERVICES -</Text>
     <Text>BUSINESS CENTER</Text>
    </Services>
    <Transportation>
     <Text>TRANSPORTATION FROM PRIMARY AIRPORT TO PROPERTY -</Text>
     <Text>RENTAL CAR</Text>
     <Text>TRANSPORTATION FROM CITY CENTER TO PROPERTY -</Text>
     <Text>RENTAL CAR</Text>
    </Transportation>
   </VendorMessages>
  </BasicPropertyInfo>
  <Guarantee>
   <DepositsAccepted>
    <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="DS" Type="DISCOVER CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA"/>
   </DepositsAccepted>
   <GuaranteesAccepted>
    <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="DS" Type="DISCOVER CARD"/>
    <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA"/>
   </GuaranteesAccepted>
  </Guarantee>
  <RoomRates>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="N1QRAC" IATA_ProductIdentification="PUBLISHED RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="001" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="03" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">10.00 PERCENT COMMISSION</Commission>
     <Text>STANDARD QUEEN</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="159.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="359.94">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="41.94"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="N1KRAC" IATA_ProductIdentification="PUBLISHED RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="002" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="03" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">10.00 PERCENT COMMISSION</Commission>
     <Text>STANDARD KING</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="169.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="382.58">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="44.58"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="S1KRAC" IATA_ProductIdentification="PUBLISHED RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="003" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="03" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">10.00 PERCENT COMMISSION</Commission>
     <Text>KING SUITE</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="199.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="450.48">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="52.48"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="APTRAC" IATA_ProductIdentification="PUBLISHED RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="004" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="03" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">10.00 PERCENT COMMISSION</Commission>
     <Text>PLAZA PENTHOUSE</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="499.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="1129.62">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="131.62"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
  </RoomRates>
  <TimeSpan Duration="0005" End="2016-10-16" Start="2016-10-14"/>
 </RoomStay>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

REQUEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"><!-- APP SOURCE REMOVED BY OP --></PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId><!-- IPCC REMOVED BY OP --></CPAId>
         <ConversationId>MyConversationID</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</Service>
         <Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1422291197</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2015-01-26T09:53:17-07:00</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2015-01-26T10:53:17-07:00</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <!-- TOKEN REMOVED BY OP -->
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0.1">
         <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count="2" />
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="0012498" />
                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>

            <TimeSpan Start="10-14" End="10-16" />
         </AvailRequestSegment>
      </HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Edit: added request, per user request. Items I removed for security have been indicated with comments.

Comment: Can you share the XML request?

Comment: @jmacagno I have appended the request to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange indeed not having that returned as usual.

The answer to your question is: No. Actually that room rate requires a deposit not a guarantee, and it is safe to say that most hotels require one of the 2, so not sending that is probably not a good idea.

In this case, you can use GDPST as deposit, since it says that it accepts credit cards, although that is in free text.

Now, as you can see in the first rate returned, inside the RoomRate element, you have: **GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D"**. The values for that attribute are D for Deposit and G for guarantee. I'm not sure if there's something for when there is no guarantee needed, haven't seen any, but it is likely a different element or the element is not returned.

In order to know the values for guarantee you can use in the OTA_HotelRes, I recommend you to check the following format finder link:
https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/Hotels/FourEasyStepstoSellaHotel/0HSellHotel.aspx?ItemID=597F73406BFE49EFB5DF100C096ABFB0

Comment: Thank you, I did attempt not sending the Type attribute and it resulted in an error. I will implement this logic and release a patch. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Works, still goofy, but I'll go with it.